# Bash: How to put hostname between quotes in file

Tags: bash, hostname

I try to add the hostname of my server in a file but it fails.
I tried:

```
HOST=`hostname`
echo ' "server": "${HOST}"' >> /myfile
```

And I tried:

```
echo ' "server": "`hostname`"' >> /myfile
```

It's important to know that I need this output in my file:

```
"server": "ip-133..."
```

Comment: `echo "\"server\":\"${HOST}\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ echo "\"server\": \"$(hostname)\"" >> myfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes don't interpolate variables. Use double or no quotes:

```
echo ' "server": "'"$HOST"'"'
echo ' "server": "'`hostname`'"'
```